# cordova6.1.1(Android platform 5.1.1) gallery image is not uploading correctly

Tags: android, cordova

uploading gallery image working properly in cordova(3.6.3) version . After upgrading cordova6.1.1(Android platform 5.1.1) gallery image is not uploading correctly. I am able to select the image from the gallery but selected image is not visible in the UI. Captured camera image is getting updated in the UI. Image selected from gallery are not getting updated. i have checked with fileEntry.js  var localURL = this.toInternalURL(); getting the url  cdvfile://localhost/content/media/external/images/media/506 and old cordova(3.6.3) version url seems like content://media/external/images/media/511.

```
 html code:
 <div><a id="fromGallery" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);"></a></div>
```

js code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady()
{
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}
function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageurl){
       imagesize(imageuri)
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

var imagesize = function(imagedata){

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imagedata,function(fileEntry){
**fileEntry.file(function(fileObj)**{


});

});
};
```

Code is not executing after fileEntry.file. 
I have checked with FileEntry.prototype.file method in FileEntry.js and alert to localURL. 
Getting different url from cordova version 3.6.3(content://media/external/images/media/511) and 6.1.1(cdvfile://localhost/content/media/external/images/media/506).
Please suggest a solution to the problem

Comment: Could you me more precise on your problem? Any sample code?

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: updated my html and js code. give some solution for my problem

Comment: @manikandangopal Have you tried my answer.

Comment: i tried mentioned below the code. it did not work. any idea apart from that one

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the resolution for my question. The problem is android native plug-ins java file inside the ***src*** directory. some of java file not replacing properly.